# Get SVN annotate information in IntelliJ IDEA 13

Tags: java, svn, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.6 ultimate with svn client 1.8.8 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

When I try to get annotate information, I get an error

> Error: svn: invalid option: --ignore-all-space
>   Type 'svn help' for usage.

IntelliJ use command line client with this settings :

```
export LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
svn $@
```

and I setup the idea64.vmoptions file with this settings :

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
```

Any advice would be appreciated.